# Will workflow correlate work after update?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

assume that I have a long running workflow.The messages are correlated using let say RequestID (Guid typed). What will happen if I do some small changes in the workflow xamlx and publish it on deployment server ? Will correlation work and be able to continue persisted to database instances which were started before change ? 
Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Persisted instances will not be able to continue after xaml update.
You can upgrade to WF 4,5 and use [Dynamic Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314052.aspx).
After that all correlations will work fine.